# ASP.NET Core AddContext

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm architecting a new App and I really unconfortable with this approach in ASP.NET Core that made "normal" adding a DbContext by using AddDbContext, in services.

I'd like to know if you guys think that using AddDbContext in ASP.NET Core isn't a bad practice, since it forces my Web App to have a dependecy on my database access layer.

I've researched a lot and it was incredible that there isn't almost anything that cover this subject.

How should I proceed to overcome this concern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> it forces my Web App to have a dependency on my database access layer

That's exactly the place where it should be: the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Your application startup code is *the* place where you glue your components together.

What else would you want, create a separate library, containing interfaces for all classes in your entire DAL, and wire that up using magic during startup?

Comment: OK. Maybe I don't really understand what does it mean. But in a simple 3-tier app, for instance, I shouldn't have web, service and data layer, on which web gets its data through service layer, and service gets its data from data layer (which actually contains dbcontext reference)?